# Can't login to computer

Tags: dual-boot, login

My computer dual boots Linux alongside Windows. I'm stuck at the login screen on Linux, where my cursor has turned into a white box, I can't input my password, and the words "Authorization failed" flashes. I can't power off the computer using the control center in the top right nor by pressing the power button on the computer. im using 22.04.4 LTS